# Cocoon like bug on exterior walls south florida

Tags: entomology, species-identification, pest-control

[image]

Can anyone tell me what this is? One side of my house has 30 to 40 of them. when I try to pick them off they leave either brown spots or fibers from the cocoon. Is there anyway to deter them?

Comment: Could you provide approximate size/dimensions. Also, given that you have so many, could you post a picture of what's inside?

Comment: Are they all "plastered" to the the side of the house as this one appears to be, or are they dangling down, too?